# Modify Ace Editor Gutter div

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, gutter

Is it possible to modify the gutter and add a custom div inside the gutter lines div?

Example :

```
        <div class="ace_layer ace_gutter-layer ace_folding-enabled" style="margin-top: 0px; height: 730px; width: 33px;">
           <div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height: 14px;">
            <div class="customDIV"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: describe more what you wanna do.

Comment: I want to show a diff like git shows. previous number and the current number of the line.

Comment: I am trying up down buttons on marked lines for jumpscroll https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73516033/ace-editor-mark-lines-jumpscroll-to-marked-lines-problem-appendchild-to-line-nr

Answer (score 0):

no, normally you html inside gutter div will be overwritten by gutter.